# SQL query to select another row with minimum and maximum of nid value

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server

I have a 3 columns

```
nid aid cst
1    1   23
2    3   45
3    1   67
4    2   34
5    3   12
6    1   6
```

Please re-read for explanation:
I have to find the cst of aid which has minimum value of nid for  example whne i select aid=1 then it must give 23 as 
it correponds to mimimum value of
nid(1) and when i select 3 it must give 45 as it has least nid(2) as compared to all other nids of aid

My try is this ad it do not work :

```
select cst from tbl 
where (nid) IN (select min(nid) from tbl) and aid=nid
```

I also have to do the same for max as i done for min.

Comment: SELECT FIRST_VALUE(cst) OVER (ORDER BY nid), LAST_VALUE(cst) OVER (ORDER BY nid) FROM tbl WHERE aid = @aid

Comment: what is i have to get all the cst corresponding aid=1 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select cst
from tbl 
where aid=1 and nid=(select min(nid) from tbl where aid=1)
```

This query will give you minimum values of `cst` for all values of `aid`

Comment: what is i have to get all the cst corresponding aid=1?

Comment: Didn't get what you are asking? Do you want all cst value for aid=1

Comment: select cst from tbl where aid=1. Use this query

Answer (score 0):

One method uses `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by aid order by cst) as seqnum
      from tbl t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Your method would work with table aliases, qualified column names, and the correct logic:

```
select t.cst
from tbl t
where t.cst = (select min(t2.cst) from tbl t2 where t2.aid = t.aid);
```

Or, more simply:

```
select aid, min(cst)
from t
group by aid;
```

Comment: i have to deal with min aand max

Comment: there is no t2 table...only one table

Answer (score 0):

```
select cst  from tbl_NID where aid =1 and  nid in ( select min (nid) from tbl_NID where aid=1  )

select cst  from tbl_NID where aid =1 and  nid like ( select min (nid) from tbl_NID where aid=1  )
```

[Example Query](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/90a2b/10)

Comment: what is i have to get all the cst corresponding aid=1 ?

Comment: it's sample query you can put you value